# Not able to dynamically set color of Vue avatar with style property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to dynamically set the `background-color property` of my Vuetify avatar but it does not seem to working. I do not want to use the color property. I have to use the background-color definition.

here is a codepen showing my issue https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/VweWvoG?editors=1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use :style syntax to bind the styles properly, this allows to use JS to call the function

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="space-around">
  
      <v-avatar style="background-color: bisque;">
        <span class="white--text headline">CJ</span>
      </v-avatar>
      <!-- this is the one working! -->
      <v-avatar :style="{ backgroundColor: getcolor('ngae')}">
        <span class="white--text headline">CJ</span>
      </v-avatar>
      
      <v-avatar :color="getcolor('name')">
        <span class="white--text headline">CJ</span>
      </v-avatar>
  
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

You can read about style bindings [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)

Comment: could do this too: ``:style="`background-color: ${getcolor('name')}`"``

Comment: @LawrenceCherone oh great to know it!